# How to forward unique_ptr with tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, unique-ptr

Imagine a function expecting rvalue reference to std::unique_ptr.

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<int>&& a);
```

In my real world example there is more than one argument, so I decided to forward arguments to it using `std::tuple<T&&>` of rvalue references - so `std::forward_as_tuple`:

```
void forward_to_foo(std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int>&&>&& t);
int main() {
   forward_to_foo(std::forward_as_tuple(std::make_unique<int>(8)));
}
```

As for now everything is ok.

Problem occurred when I wanted to "unpack" this tuple

```
void forward_to_foo(std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int>&&>&& t)
{
   foo(std::get<0>(t));
}
```

I got this error on gcc4.9 with c++14:

```
error: cannot bind 'std::unique_ptr<int>' lvalue to 'std::unique_ptr<int>&&'
    foo(std::get<0>(t));
```

My question: what is the problem here? Why `std::get<I>(t)` from tuple of rvalue references returns lvalue?

Comment: Because `t` is an lvalue. Use `std::get<0>(std::move(t));`.

Comment: `std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int>&&> t = std::forward_as_tuple<std::make_unique<int>(8));` - this gives a dangling reference, so UB.

Comment: Can you please post code that doesn't have unrelated syntax errors in it?  Simplify, then **actually reproduce the problem** in the simplified code.  If you simplify down to code that has different problems, or doesn't have your problem, then the code is often worse than useless.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help.

Comment: @ecatmur - I hope I fixed.

Comment: @Yakk I made it more related to real life example.

Comment: @piotr the code posted still has unrelated syntax errors in it.  Please post code that actually produces the error you are asking about.  Put it into a compiler, and compile it.  Your brackets aren't even matching!

Comment: @Yakk - fixed. ideone: http://ideone.com/mDsrtJ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what is the problem here?

You need `std::move` to move from an *lvalue* expression:

```
foo(std::move(std::get<0>(t)));
```

> Why `std::get<I>(t)` from tuple of rvalue references returns lvalue?

Because it returns an *lvalue* reference to an element of the tuple. In general, the result of a function returning an *lvalue* reference is an *lvalue*, since it denotes an existing object not a temporary.

Comment: Yes, you are right; I simplified my example too much. My real life example required passing tuple as const lvalue reference - thus I cannot do `std::move`. This `const reference` is because of some legacy library I need to use. But anyway, you answered this question. I will create new one.

Comment: So this is close.  The move, however, should be on the `t` not on the entire `get` expression: [std::get<0>(std::move(t))](http://ideone.com/UHnLP5).  Once the `t` is forwarded as an rvalue, `get` returns an rvalue.  The construct above has the "problem" that even if `t` contained lvalue references, the `std::move` would still move them out.  With `std::get<N>(std::move(t))` only values and rvalue references are returned as rvalue references.  That tends to be safer, and errors that result often indicate a logic problem elsewhere, at least in forwarding code.

Comment: Yes, I misread the question and didn't spot the references all over the place. I should probably delete the answer; there's far too much indirection to think about on a Monday.